# Clojurescript date timepicker with cljsjs/react-day-picker

Tags: clojurescript, react-day-picker, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I am new to `clojure` and `clojurescript`. I just to know how I can implement this library in `clojurescript`.

This is the link to the library: https://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/basic

I have required the library in my name space like so :

```
(ns woot (:require [cljsjs.react-day-picker]))
```

But I do not know how to proceed from here

And when I try

```
(js/react-day-picker)
```

I get this error

```
#object[ReferenceError ReferenceError: react_day_picker is not defined]
 (<NO_SOURCE_FILE>)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLJSJS works by providing an *externs file* which is used so that the ClojureScript compiler avoids messing up the names when performing optimizations. If you look at the end of the file [react-day-picker.ext.js](https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/blob/master/react-day-picker/resources/cljsjs/react-day-picker/react-day-picker.ext.js) in Github, you'll notice that it exports the name `DayPicker` in the global scope, so you probably want to do something like `(js/DayPicker.)` to create a new instance of `DayPicker`.

That being said, I'd recommend you looking into [Shadow-CLJS](http://shadow-cljs.org) because the integration with the NPM ecosystem will be much more familiar. I have [this repo with a small demo of react-intl](https://github.com/dfuenzalida/cljs-react-intl) and it should be easy to replace a few bits and have the basic react-day-picker example working.

**Edit**: I gave it a try:

- Clone my cljs-react-intl repo
- Install react-day-picker with npm: `yarn install react-day-picker`
- Edit the file `assets/index.html` to include the required stylesheet:

```
   <head>
     <title>minimal react-intl example</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <!- ADD THE FOLLOWING -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/react-day-picker@7.4.0/lib/style.css">
   </head>
```

- Update the main.cljs file to call the day-picker classes:

```
(ns app.main
  (:require ["react-day-picker" :as dp]
            [reagent.core :as r]))

;; App

(defn example-app []
  [:p
   [:div "Here is a day picker:"]
   [:> dp/DayPicker]
   ])

;; App initialization

(defn mount-root []
  (r/render [example-app] (.getElementById js/document "app")))

(defn main! []
  (mount-root)
  (println "[core]: loading"))

(defn reload! []
  (mount-root)
  (println "[core] reloaded"))
```

- Start the app in Dev mode:

```
yarn run html
yarn shadow-cljs watch app
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]