# Javascript to Clojurescript interop with react-spring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clojurescript, react-spring

I am trying to implement `react-spring` (https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/basics) into my Clojurescript proct and I am struggling to translate this to `clojurescript`

```
import {useSpring, animated} from 'react-spring'
function App() {
  const props = useSpring({opacity: 1, 
                           from: {opacity: 0}})
  return <animated.div style={props}>I will fade in</animated.div>
}
```

So far this is what I have done:
I have required the following:

```
(:require 
[useSpring]
[animated])
```

and in a let block I have something like so:

```
(defn example-app []
   (let [props (useSpring (->js {:opacity 1
                                 :from  {opacity: 0}}))]
    (def props props)
    [:animated.div {:style props} "I will fade in"]
))
```

The variable `props` returns this :

```
#js{:opacity #object[AnimatedValue [object Object]]}
```

Than this is how I render the animated object

```
(react-dom/render
(hx/f [example-app])
(goog.dom/getElement "example-app"))
```

This is the **error** that I get

```
#object[Error Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {ns, name, fqn, _hash, cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition0$, cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition1$}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
in core$example_app]
```

What am I doing wrong?  What am I missing?

Comment: whats the React error?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the error. Thanks

Comment: See this answer for a similar example of another React library consumed from a ClojureScript project: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58871983/483566

Comment: @DenisFuenzalida see above what I have also tried. I do not use reagent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to get a basic example to work, hopefully it will help you get started:

- I cloned my example repo: https://github.com/dfuenzalida/cljs-react-intl/ (I created this for a test on react-intl, will work for you too)
- From the checked out repo, I installed `react-spring` with `yarn install react-spring`
- I edited the file `shadow-cljs.edn` to add the dependency on `lilactown/hx`:

```clj
{:source-paths ["src"]
 :dependencies [[lilactown/hx "0.5.3"]]
 :dev-http {8080 "target/"}
 :builds {:app {:output-dir "target/"
                :asset-path "."
                :target :browser
                :modules {:main {:init-fn app.main/main!}}
                :devtools {:after-load app.main/reload!}}}}
```

I replaced the contents of `src/app/main.cljs` with the react-spring example, adapted a bit:

```clj
(ns app.main
  (:require [hx.react :as hx :refer [defnc]]
            ["react-dom" :as react-dom]
            ["react-spring" :as spring]))

(defnc AppComponent [{:keys [title]}]
  (let [props (spring/useSpring (clj->js {:opacity 1 :from {:opacity 0}}))]
    [:<>
     [spring/animated.div {:style props} title]]))

;; App initialization

(defn mount-root []
  (react-dom/render
   (hx/f [AppComponent {:title "I will fade in"}])
   (js/document.getElementById "app")))

(defn main! []
  (mount-root)
  (println "[core]: loading"))

(defn reload! []
  (mount-root)
  (println "[core] reloaded"))
```

Finally, ran `yarn install` to download any missing deps and then `yarn run html` and `yarn shadow-cljs watch app` to start the compiler in watch mode. The console will show something like:

```
$ yarn shadow-cljs watch app
yarn run v1.17.3
$ /tmp/cljs-react-intl/node_modules/.bin/shadow-cljs watch app
shadow-cljs - config: /tmp/cljs-react-intl/shadow-cljs.edn  cli version: 2.8.74  node: v10.16.0
shadow-cljs - updating dependencies
...
shadow-cljs - dependencies updated
shadow-cljs - HTTP server available at http://localhost:8080
shadow-cljs - server version: 2.8.74 running at http://localhost:9630
shadow-cljs - nREPL server started on port 43685
shadow-cljs - watching build :app
[:app] Configuring build.
[:app] Compiling ...
[:app] Build completed. (156 files, 11 compiled, 0 warnings, 9.21s)
```

Once you load your app at http://localhost:8080, you should see something like:

[image: screenshot of code and browser]

The animation actually works, but I couldn't figure how to make the other examples to work (eg. the scroll example or the counter).

I hope this helps!

Comment: What does is this `:<>`?

Comment: Ahh I see react fragments